# How to plot exponential distribution in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have been trying all day to plot a simple theoretical exponential distribution, with beta value of 15.

Have tried the followning, with many, many variations:

```
data exponential;
do x = 0 to 100 by 5;
density = cdf('exponential',x< ,15>
output exponential;
end;
run;
```

I am following the recommendations found in the link below, and in various help documents

(http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/63354/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0n7cce4a3gfqkn1vr0p1x0of99s.htm#n0p4ehagihl2zcn10orv1azqbr26)

Somehow, however, SAS just won't have it:

```
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, a quoted string,a numeric constant, a datetime constant, a
missing value, bitstring, INPUT, PUT.         

ERROR 388-185: Expecting an arithmetic operator.  

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
```

Would someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data exponential;
   do x = 0 to 100 by 5;
      density = cdf('exponential',x,15);
      output exponential;
      end;
   run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't include the <> symbols that the manual page is using to designate optional parameters.

```
density = cdf('exponential',X,15) ;
```

Comment: Tried removing those (now and before).

Still get the following errors:

ERROR 388-185: Expecting an arithmetic operator.

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

Comment: Also, if I add the semicolon, it says the CDF function does not have enough arguments :/

Comment: If you replace your posted code with the line I fixed it runs fine.  You probably have confused the poor thing. Try submitting a bunch of right parentheses. Or just re-start SAS so that you have a fresh session.

Comment: Ah "now" I see the thing with the paranthesis, giving an upvote for that ^^